# Could not install RWeka package on R

Tags: r, installation, rweka

I tried different ways to install RWeka package on R but could not find any success.

I could not install RWeka though trying different methods:

**1. Install normally**

```
install.packages("RWeka")
cannot open compressed file 'RWekajars/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

**2. Install from URL**

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/RWeka_0.4-24.zip")
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

**3. Install from local (after downloading the zip file and place it into a directory)**

```
install_local("RWeka_0.4-24.zip")
ERROR: installing binary package failed
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/library/RWeka'
```

Could somebody help me with this?
Many thanks

Comment: I tried to install `RWeka` just now and it works fine for me. So, it's probably something wrong on your end. Sorry, I've got nothing more useful...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error. 
After I run the javareconf comand in the Ubuntu:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
...

sudo R 
> install.packages("RWeka")
```

I tried to install again and it works for me.

Comment: Or run as administrator on Windows : )

Answer (score 0):

My install of both RWeka and RWekajar worked fine onboth Windows 7 and Debian Linux on Intel i5 with both R 3.2.3 and R 3.2.4 following exactly the first (and second) methods you used. However I have gotten the same error installing or even upgrading other packages and the problem has never been exactly obvious.

However, that said, clearly it suggests you are not pointed to an accessible file either on the repository or even where it ends up on your system after download or after unpacking (you never can tell which) but it is worth trying to see which  part is failing.

Make sure you are root on linuz or running R etc as admin on Windows. Check the paths to the libraries in the setup. Sometimes the install process can't find the R/R3.2.3/library/ directory and will default to ./Documents/R/.../library check that too.

Check that the environment variables for R and Weka are not corrupted.
Also, for what it is worth, make sure all dependencies are being dealt with as onof those may be actually what is inaccessible, especially rJava as Weka is written in Java  (which must have an accessible jvm installed).

Often, there are some packages I never figure out theproblem with this error message ( and would welcome some experienced insight as well myself). And sometimes, after I check and fiddle with the above things and when I go back and try the install, it works. :-/

Answer (score 0):

1. I installed the last version of java 
   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. In R Studio:

   `install.packages("rJava", type = "source")` 
   `install.packages("RWeka", type = "source")`